# Why request.args returns empty ImmutableMultiDict?

Tags: flask

I am trying to obtain arguments passed from `url_for()` function. But it keeps returning an empty ImmutableMultiDict to me. Below is my code.

**hosts.html**

```
<p>
  <a href="{{ url_for('svc_instance_deploy',
                       service_id=service_id,
                       host_id=host_id) }}">
  <span class="label label-success">Install Software</span>
  </a>
</p>
```

**view.py**

```
@app.route('/deploy/<service_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/deploy/<service_id>/<host_id>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def svc_instance_deploy(service_id, host_id=0):
    print(request.args)
```

When click the link on `hosts.html`, both browser and server side make no error. Except that it prints an empty ImmutableMultiDict to me.

Why can't I get the arguments passed by `url_for()` function? How could I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your full request? using `curl` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue.

Turns out I use the wrong `property` of `Request` object. When we obtain arguments in view function, we should use `request.view_args` instead of `request.args`.